# Is a bang pattern on unit really needed here?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

While hacking Stack, I found [this](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/src/System/Process/Read.hs#L345-L346):

```hs
!() <- atomicModifyIORef (eoExeCache eo) $ \m' ->
    (Map.insert name epath m', ())
```

HLint says: “remove that thing”. But I don't think it's a typo. Is there any reason to ever write `!()`?

Comment: Because `()` is already in normal form (and, therefore, in WHNF), I don't think there is any point in using a bang pattern, here.

Comment: A bang before a constructor pattern is pointless -- we are forcing the value anyway.

Comment: Some investigation of the repo reveals that this bang pattern was introduced by Michael Snoyman in [this commit](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/commit/5039c19655f496926fa882c93efe2867afb97468). Perhaps you should post your question in the repo's issue tracker and ask him what he was thinking at the time of writing it. Michael knows his stuff, so I'd say he simply left this superfluous bang in by an oversight.

Comment: Maybe it was just to make it more obvious that a forced evaluation is being made?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If in doubt (and not in a hurry) consult the [specification](https://www.haskell.org/report).

The expression

```
do !() <- foo
   bar
```

[desugars](https://www.haskell.org/report/node/2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) to

```
let ok !() = bar
    ok _   = fail ..
in foo >>= ok
```

By the [rules for function definition](https://www.haskell.org/report/node/2010/haskellch4.html#x10-830004.4.3) this is equivalent to

```
let ok = \x -> case x of !() -> bar
                         _   -> fail ...
in foo >>= ok
```

Now the [rules for bang patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) are in the GHC user guide, as it is non-standard haskell. there we find that we can rewrite this into

```
let ok = \x -> x `seq` (case x of () -> bar
                                  _  -> fail ...)
in foo >>= ok
```

Now [`seq` is defined](https://www.haskell.org/report/node/2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1260006.2) in terms of its argument being ⊥ or not. So either `x` is ⊥, but then the second argument to `seq`, namely the `case x of ...` is also ⊥ according to the [semantics of pattern matching](https://www.haskell.org/report/node/2010/haskellch3.html#x8-610003.17.3). Or `x` is not ⊥, and the `seq` equals its second argument. In either case, the above code is identical to

```
let ok = \x -> case x of () -> bar
                         _  -> fail ...
in foo >>= ok
```

which, tracing back these steps, is equivalent to

```
do () <- foo
   bar
```

So in conclusion: There is no reason to do that in a `do` expression.

There is, however, a difference between

```
let () = foo
in bar
```

(where `foo` will never be evaluated) and

```
let !() = foo
in bar
```

because let-expressions have special provisions in the [semantics for bang patterns](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html).